# Count number of instrution's in an X86 assembly language code

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I need to count the number of instructions that will be generated for an simple assembly language code . So that even if there is any loop I can count the number of instructions in that loop also.I just need it so that i can determine how many times i can use -p option for each instruction's in he code. I am using masm on widows xp computer .

Comment: It's not clear why the source code isn't enough. Can you give an example? Also, what does the `-p` option do?

Comment: @alex -p option . is like step over option in compilers . Its helpful in trace the code line by line. when i give this command debug program.exe with - p option . It gives me the contents of all registers for that instruction . if press -p again it moves to second instruction in the code and gives me the content of the registers for that instruction execution . Like wise for every instruction i need to determine how many times i need to give that -p option . I can count the number of lines for simple code which doesn't contain branches and loops . But code with loops its difficult to determine

Comment: It's more than "difficult," it's intractable.

Comment: @user953131: Can't you just set a breakpoint after the assembly, and let the debugger execute up to that breakpoint (thereby skipping to the end of the assembly language code without needing to know how many instructions you've skipped)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually much more difficult than you would think. (Some would say impossible--see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

If the code relies on any sort of data (e.g. loading values from RAM), its behavior could change drastically based on what the data contains, and this will affect the number of instructions executed. e.g. if it's a loop, it will probably load its iteration count from memory somewhere. So it could be 100 instructions executed, or 100000000 instructions.